# Why can't $e^{x^2}$ be integrated

Tags: real-analysis

My teacher told me that not only do we have to use the erf function to approximate error, but that it is proved impossible to integrate in real analysis (at least not Riemann-integrable). Is there a name for this proof, and can I have it? I am not a mathematician, but such a simple function has been around and it irks me terribly and need a *detailed* proof for closure.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523824/what-is-the-antiderivative-of-e-x2

Comment: It *is* Reimann-integrable. Its just that no antiderivative of $x \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \exp(x^2)$ can be written down in terms of certain operations applied to certain primitive functions. (Not really that profound, imo). By an antiderivative of $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, I just mean a function $g : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g' = f$.

Comment: This question belongs to the **Differential Field**

Comment: Are you aderssing the problem of Exp[x^2] ?

Comment: @user18921, **Riemann** ;)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz, lol thanks.

Comment: @Teg : First question : "Can the function 1/x be integrated ?" Loosely answer from someone who doesn't known the function ln(x) : "No, it doesn't". Second question:  "Can the function Exp(-x²) be integrated ?" Loosely answer from someone who doesn't known the function Erf(x) : "No, it doesn't". There are many questions and answers of this kind from people who doesn't know about special functions. The subject is discussed in the paper "Safari in the country of Special Functions" (overview for general public) : http://www.scribd.com/JJacquelin/documents

Comment: I'd say that this is not a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523824/what-is-the-antiderivative-of-e-x2, since this question asks for a proof, and no proof was considered there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your teacher probably said that $\exp(-x^2)$ (or $\exp(x^2)$) does not have an antiderivative that can be expressed using [elementary functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function):

> In mathematics, an elementary function is a function of one variable built from a finite number of exponentials, logarithms, constants, and nth roots through composition and combinations using the four elementary operations (+ – × ÷).

The set of elementary functions forms a field of functions, equipped with a *derivative* operation: a differential field of functions. These kind of fields have been introduced by Liouville, in order to demonstrate his famous [theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) which states that

> the antiderivatives of certain elementary functions cannot themselves be expressed as elementary functions.

The proof uses algebra in the differential field of functions. It would be by all means not productive to reproduce it here, but there are some references you might want to check:

- The modern version of the demonstration of this theorem is an [open-access article by Rosenlicht](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102991609).
- A [post by Matthew Wiener](http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/43d5fc44bc713171) provides several examples.

Comment: You can't usub using $u = x^2$? Then $du = 2xdx$ oh wait nevermind...

Answer (score 0):

As V. Rossetto wrote, your teacher more than likely told that the antiderivative of such a function cannot be obtained on the basis of simple functions.

For this integrand, the antiderivative is  Sqrt[Pi] Erfi[x] / 2, where Erfi[x]is the imaginary error function Erf(iz)/i. The error function Erf[x] is the integral of the Gaussian distribution, given by Erf[z]= (2 /Sqrt[Pi]) Integral[Exp[-t^2],{t,0,z}].

I hope that you better percieve the vicious circle we move around.