# Integral of $\int\frac{1}{\log x}dx$

Tags: integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

What is the value of

$$\int\frac{1}{\log x}dx$$
I have tried many times, but failed everytime.

Can anyone help me out in solving this question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Comment: $\frac{1}{\log x}$ has no elementary primitive.

Comment: This is the definition of the logarithmic inetgral.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824883/integration-int-frac1-lnxdx?noredirect=1#comment5824668_2824883

Answer (score 4):

If you don't like special functions symbols:

$\int\dfrac{1}{\log x}dx=\int\dfrac{\ln10}{\ln x}dx$

Let $u=\ln x$ ,

Then $x=e^u$

$dx=e^u~du$

$\therefore\int\dfrac{\ln10}{\ln x}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{e^u\ln10}{u}du$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{u^n\ln10}{n!u}du$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{u^{n-1}\ln10}{n!}du$

$=\int\left(\dfrac{\ln10}{u}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{u^{n-1}\ln10}{n!}\right)du$

$=\ln10\ln u+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{u^n\ln10}{n!n}+C$

$=\ln10\ln\ln x+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(\ln x)^n\ln10}{n!n}+C$

Comment: What is the valor of n in this context?

Comment: $\log$ probably denotes the natural logarithm here.

Comment: I think that it could be interesting to justify the change in the order of summation (for the readers).

Comment: Correct, but not useful if one wishes to integrate over $[0,1-\delta)$ for $0<\delta<1$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $\log x$ denotes the natural logarithm.

The antiderivative you are analyzing has no expression in terms of “elementary function”, just like the case of the [antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523824/what-is-the-antiderivative-of-e-x2/523831#523831).

You can transform it in various ways; with the substitution $t=-\log x$, we have $x=e^{-t}$ and $dx=-e^{-t}\,dt$, so we obtain
$$
\int\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt
$$
but this doesn't help much.

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html for those two closely related integrals.

Comment: You can Taylor expand the $e^{-t}$ to get a series expansion.