# INTEGRATION $\int\frac{1}{\ln{x}}dx$?

Tags: integration

How do we evaluate $\int\frac{1}{\ln{x}}dx$?
Is it a special integral, or some simple function, or what substitution will help?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Answer (score 2):

It is a special function, the [logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function). In particular, $\frac 1{\ln x}$ has no elementary primitive.