# How to solve $\int \frac{f(x)}{f^{\prime}(x)} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^{\infty}$ with $f^{\prime}\not\equiv0$.

There exists a formula to solve the integral
$$\int \frac{f(x)}{f^{\prime}(x)} dx?$$

Since I know that is
$$\int \frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{f(x)} dx=\log(|f(x)|) +c,$$

I was wondering how to act when in the first case.

I hope someone could help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For an arbitrary function $h$ and $f = e^h$ that would be $\int \frac{dx}{h'(x)}$, therefore I doubt that there is a general formula.

Comment: @MartinR  You observation reduces to $[(\log f)']^{-1}={f\over f'}.$

Comment: There is no known formula for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\int \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} dx$ can not be expressed in terms of $f$ and elementary functions of $f$ for arbitrary functions $f$, as this example demonstrates:

Consider
$$
 f(x) = e^{x \log x - x}
$$
for $x > 1$. Then
$$
 \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = \frac{1}{\log(x)}\, ,
$$
but that has no antiderivative in terms of elementary function, see for example [Integral of $\int\frac{1}{\log x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/710808/42969) (and the references therein).

Comment: then for which kind of nontrivial (I mean e.g. $f(x)=x$) functions it is possible to evaluate that integral?

Comment: If $f$ is rational then $f/f'$ is also rational. Similar for rational functions of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$. I am not aware of a general characterisations of functions $f$ for which $f/f'$ is elementary integrable.