# How to know if the function is non integrable?

Tags: calculus

Lets say we have a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. How is it possible to tell that we cannot find the anti-derivative of the function? Is there any specific test for it?

Comment: Do you mean anti-derivative or anti-derivative in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: I think that you want [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, functions have no closed-form antiderivative. :-)

Comment: If you mean in terms of elementary functions, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative

Answer (score 0):

If you mean anti-derivatives in general, there seems to be no simple test.

However mathematicians have proven that certain classes of functions have an anti-derivative.
E.g. a continous function has an anti-derivative.
So all tests that prove a function to be continous would apply.

For the more weird cases see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative#Antiderivatives_of_non-continuous_functions).

Comment: how about exp(x^2) ?  that can be proved to be not integrable without the error function, which is defined in terms of the integral of exp(x^2) - if a function is continuous and continuously differentiable, then it is always possible to integrate its Taylor Series expansion - then call that function

Comment: You mean $e^{-x^2}$. Has an antiderivative. That it is defined in terms of an integral expression or a special function is just a matter of convenience.

Comment: what is the antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$ or $e^{x^2}$?  Since they are surely continuous?

Comment: @AndrewDeighton $f(x)=\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt$ has the property that $f'(x)=e^{-x^2}$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523824/what-is-the-antiderivative-of-e-x2/523831#523831