# Trying to explore definite integration and its source of definition.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose if $\phi(x)$ and its derivative is $f(x)$

Let's try to find following
$$\int f(x)$$
$$\int f(x)=\phi(x)+c$$

So in indefinite integration we say that integrand would be the derivative of integral.

But as we raise limits to integration like following

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)$$

We say that it is actually equal to net area under $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$ provided $f(x)$ is continuous in $(a,b)$. By "**net area**", I mean $\text {area}$ above $X \text { axis }-\text{area}$  below $X \text{ axis }$.

So by this definition we can say,

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}h\left(f(a)+f(a+h)+f(a+2h)\cdots\cdots f(a+(n-1)h)\right)\tag{1}$$

In above equation $n\rightarrow \infty$

But we also magically say that $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)=\phi(b)-\phi(a)$$, how we can say this because by definition this looks totally different. Any proof? I didn't find the explanation for $$\phi(b)-\phi(a)$$.

I tried to prove it. My attempt is as follows:-

$$f(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\phi(a+h)-\phi(a)}{h}$$
$$f(a+h)=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\phi(a+2h)-\phi(a+h)}{h}$$
$$f(a+2h)=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\phi(a+3h)-\phi(a+2h)}{h}$$

So by this we can write $f(a+(n-1)h)=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\phi(a+nh)-\phi(a+(n-1)h)}{h}$

Putting these values in equation $1$

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}h\cdot\dfrac{\left(\phi(a+h)-\phi(a)+\phi(a+2h)-\phi(a+h)+\phi(a+3h)-\phi(a+2h)\cdot\cdots+\phi(a+nh)-\phi(a+(n-1)h)\right)}{h}$$
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\phi(a+nh)-\phi(a)$$

As we know $a+nh=b$

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)=\phi(b)-\phi(a)$$

So we proved everything but still we were able to prove this when we had the definition of $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)$ in place. How on earth would somebody be able to construct this definition when we just know $\int f(x)=\phi(x)+c$?

Comment: You're not using the standard definition of a definite integral. Use Riemann sums. The connection between definite integrals and antiderivatives is given by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: You just showed how to express values of $f$ in terms of differential quotients of $\phi$ based only on the knowledge that $\phi$ is its antiderivative. Then adding them up we see that the middles cancel out and the areas of rectangles add up to the overall difference of $\phi$ values. This is roughly how the FTC was originally proved, only it was done in geometric language of areas and tangents, see [Barrow's Fundamental Theorem](https://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/barrows-fundamental-theorem). The definition with limits came 200 years later.

Comment: @OliverJones, but according to fundamental theorem of calculus, standard definition of definite integral is the same as I mentioned and textbooks also mention the same definition, what am I missing here?

Comment: @user3290550 You're not missing anything. Your definition is correct; it's just not standard. Does your text mention Riemann sums?

Comment: @user3290550 Your proof of the fundamental theorem is also unusual.

Comment: @user3290550 Finally, I'm not sure what you're asking with your last question.

Comment: in my proof, by mistake I wrote $\phi(a)$ as $\phi(a+(n-1)h)$, I corrected that, if you are referring to that. Otherwise I don't see any other thing which is unusual.

In my textbooks, reimann sums are not discussed

Comment: @user3290550 No, that's not what I meant. What's unusual is that the fundamental theorem of calculus is usually proved using the result $\displaystyle{\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)dt=f(x)}$.

Comment: @user3290550 Your last question is odd. The definite integral came first; antiderivatives came later after they discovered the fundamental theorem.

Comment: @user3290550 Actually, I do have a problem with your proof. How do you prove $\displaystyle{f(a)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\phi(a+h)-\phi(a)}{h}}$?

Comment: because $f(x)$ is the derivative of $\phi(x)$, i wrote that in the beginning itself

Comment: @user3290550 Okay. Your proof is fine then.

Comment: so now did you understand my question, I will just again summarize it, "we were able to prove $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx=\phi(b)-\phi(a)$ only by the definition of definite integral. So I wanted to know the proof of that definition."

Comment: @user3290550 The point you seem to be missing is that the definite integral is defined without reference to an antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

Let's limit ourselves to continuous functions over intervals.

Your “proof” is essentially correct, but it begs the question. More precisely, *how do you know that every continuous function $f$ over the interval $[a,b]$ has an antiderivative?*

If you can *produce* one, then there is no problem, but can you show a function $\varphi$ such that its derivative is
$$
f(x)=\sqrt[3]{\arctan\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+9}-\log(13^x+1)\bigr)}
$$
or, more simply, $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$?

The fundamental theorem of calculus does exactly that: it shows that every continuous function over an interval $I$ has an antiderivative.

Let $f$ be a continuous function over the interval $[a,b]$. A *partition* $P$ of $[a,b]$ is a finite sequence $P=\{x_0=a,x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n=b\}$, with $x_0<x_1<\dots<x_{n-1}<x_n$; the *lower sum* relative to $P$ is
$$
L(P)=\sum_{k=1}^n m_k(x_{k}-x_{k-1})
$$
where $m_k$ is the minimum of $f$ over the interval $[x_{k-1},x_k]$. The *upper sum* is
$$
U(P)=\sum_{k=1}^n M_k(x_{k}-x_{k-1})
$$
where $M_k$ is the maximum of $f$ over the interval $[x_{k-1},x_k]$. The big result is that

*the infimum of the upper sums equals the supremum of the lower sums.*

Then we can define
$$
\int_a^b f(t)\,dt
$$
to be this common infimum and supremum. Next, we can define
$$
\varphi(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt
$$
for $x\in[a,b]$ and prove that $\varphi'(x)=f(x)$, for every $x\in(a,b)$ (the fundamental theorem of calculus). As a consequence of the fact that two antiderivatives of $f$ differ by a constant, we can now state that, if $\varphi$ is ***any*** antiderivative of $f$, then
$$
\int_a^b f(t)\,dt=\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)
$$
Without the FTC and the previous definition of the integral, you cannot know that an antiderivative exists to begin with.

Comment: Note: If a function is not derivative of some function, then we can't calculate $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$. Is there any confusion in this, its the basic foundation of integration. Any counter example?

Comment: @user3290550 As I said, the problem is in the other direction: can you prove ***without*** defining the integral that a continuous function has an antiderivative?

Comment: ok , I understood your confusion, let me clear that. 

Q-$1$: If the derivative of a function is continuous, is that function continuous. (Yes or No)

Comment: If Yes, then it means if the derivative is continuous, then its anti-derivative would be continuous.

Comment: Statement 1:-If the derivative of a function is continuous, then the function would be continuous.

Statement 2:- If the function is continuous, then its anti-derivative would be continuous.

Statement 1 and Statement 2 are same. Now its upon you to think whether they are true or not.

Comment: @user3290550 Last time: how do you know that a continuous function has an antiderivative? Of course this antiderivative would be continuous, being differentiable by definition. But this is irrelevant until you prove its *existence*.

Comment: ok so you mean to say that my proof is valid only when there exists an anti-derivative? If yes, then do we calculate those definite integrals which don't have anit-derivative as limit of sum or more mathematically "Riemann sum"

Comment: @user3290550 Continuous functions *do* have antiderivatives. In general, however, they cannot be expressed in terms of “elementary functions”. And generally you *can't* compute integrals in closed form. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523824/what-is-the-antiderivative-of-e-x2/523831#523831